# How can I get a hook after a promise update the DOM

Tags: javascript, promise, svelte

I got a code to maintain and it's similar to it:

```
{#await details}
    {#each values as value, i}
        <td id="{`${config.id}_${i}`}">{value}</td>
    {/each}
{:then details_result}
    {#each details_result as detail, i}
        <td id="{`${config.id}_${i}`}" class:detail="{detail.class}">{detail.value}</td>
    {/each}
{/await}
```

I have to bind some events to this `<td>` with jQuery ([bootstrap popovers](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/popovers/)) and I'm having some problems when I should call this event binding mainly because Svelte removes the `<td>` inside `#await`, once `:then` is called, then placing the old `<td>` by the new one.

---

First I tried to bind this event inside Svelte [`afterUpdate`](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/update) function. The problem with it is that this function is only called after the `#await` `<td>` placement. `:then` `<td>` placement does not fire `afterUpdate`.

```
afterUpdate(() => {
    values.forEach((value, i) => { $(`#${config.id}_${i}`).popover(); });
})
```

---

Second I tried to bind this event inside the `then()` onFulfilled function of `details` promise, but despite I'm calling the event binding after the promise got resolved, Svelte does not update the DOM with the new `<td>`, then I'm still binding the event in the old `<td>`.

```
$: details = (...) => {
    [...]
    return new Promise(...).then(() => {
        values.forEach((value, i) => { $(`#${config.id}_${i}`).popover(); });
        [...]
    });
}();
```

How can I have a callback/hook after the `<td>` from Svelts's `:then` get inserted? Or, optionally, how can I force Svelte to keep the `<td>` HTML element reference?

Comment: Can you not delegate the event handling to suitable static container(s), for example the `<table>`, `<tbody>` or `<tr>` element in which these `<td>` elements sit? jQuery provides for this with `.on( events [, selector ] [, data ] )`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can get references to the DOM elements with the `bind:this` directive, but that would be a lot of bookkeeping to keep track of created and destroyed elements as the list changes.

For what you want, you should probably use an [action](https://svelte.dev/docs#use_action). It attaches a custom function to DOM elements lifecycle. The function gets called when an element is created, and you can also provide a cleanup function that is called when the element is destroyed.

It would look something like that:

```html
<script>
  export let items = []

  const openPopover = el => { ... }

  // this is the action function
  const popover = el => {

    // do magic with DOM element
    el.addEventListener('click', openPopover)

    const destroy = () => {
      // cleanup if you need
      el.removeEventListener('click', openPopover)
    }

    return { destroy }
  }
</script>

{#each item of items}
  <!-- our function will be called for every td element -->
  <td use:popover>
    {item.name}
  </td>
{/each}
```